# Group by and mean on dataset in R

Tags: r, summarize

I want to calculate the mean of different triplicates, but can't seem to figure out a good way to do that. I've tried grouping and summarising my dataset, but still no luck. I've used the following code to trim my dataset :

```
Data_mini <- 
  Trimmed_Data %>% 
  group_by(Component.Name, Sample.Name) %>%
  summarise(Area.Ratio)
        summarise(DF_ABCR, mymean = mean(Area.Ratio))
```

I have a dummy dataset with component name, sample name and area ratio. I need to calculate the mean for A1_ABCR1, B1_ABCR1 and C1_ABCR1 (sample name) for each component name. See image for a visual overview of the dataset. Can anyone share their view on how to best tackle this problem? Thank you in advance :) [Dummy dataset visual overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxiY8.png)

Comment: Please share a small sample data as copy/pasteable code, not as a picture--we can't run code on a picture of data. `dput()` is a good way to do that, e.g., `dput(Trimmed_Data[1:10, ])` will share the first 10 rows of your data. Choose a suitable small subset that illustrates the problem, and please be clear about your desired output for the sample input.

Comment: It sounds like you want `Trimmed_Data %>% group_by(Component.Name, Sample.Name) %>% summarise(Mean.Area.Ratio = mean(Area.Ratio))`. But squinting at your picture, it seems like `Area.Ratio` may be a string with commas and stuff, not a numeric. So converting that may be your real issue. Hard to tell without sample data to work with.

Comment: I agree. For starters you are missing a pipe between the first and second summarize(), also it is unclear what is DC_ABCR, is this a existing vector? or are you attempting to regroup by a new variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample data:

```
Trimmed_Data <- data.frame(Sample.Name = c("A1_ABCR1", "B1_ABCR1", "C1_ABCR1", "A1_ABCR1", "B1_ABCR1", "C1_ABCR1"),
                             Component.Name = c("BAD_acetylcarnitine", "BAD_acetylcarnitine", "BAD_acetylcarnitine", "BAD_alanine", "BAD_alanine", "BAD_alanine"),
                             Area.Ratio = runif(6, 0, 100))
```

Sample data:

```
  Sample.Name      Component.Name Area.Ratio
1    A1_ABCR1 BAD_acetylcarnitine   70.51099
2    B1_ABCR1 BAD_acetylcarnitine   48.85098
3    C1_ABCR1 BAD_acetylcarnitine   36.42945
4    A1_ABCR1         BAD_alanine   22.29663
5    B1_ABCR1         BAD_alanine   63.06249
6    C1_ABCR1         BAD_alanine   78.02675
```

You can use this code to calculate the mean per area ratio:

```
Data_mini <- 
    Trimmed_Data %>% 
    group_by(Component.Name, Sample.Name) %>%
    summarise(mean.Area.Ratio = mean(Area.Ratio))
  
  Data_mini
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   Component.Name [2]
  Component.Name      Sample.Name mean.Area.Ratio
  <chr>               <chr>                 <dbl>
1 BAD_acetylcarnitine A1_ABCR1               70.5
2 BAD_acetylcarnitine B1_ABCR1               48.9
3 BAD_acetylcarnitine C1_ABCR1               36.4
4 BAD_alanine         A1_ABCR1               22.3
5 BAD_alanine         B1_ABCR1               63.1
6 BAD_alanine         C1_ABCR1               78.0
```